# Is there a iCal or meeting invite like generator?

Tags: outlook, calendar, icalendar, outlook-calendar, oft

I have a team that rotates support but needs to send out calendar invites with a non changing group of users it needs to be sent to and CC'ed to. Everything I find online is for personal appointments and not calendar events. I have a template for the subject and body of the email and would like a template that users can just click and open the event in outlook and change the dates only.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood your question, but the iCalendar format is only intended to propagate an existing event. For what you want, you need to create an event.